# How do I prove that every open interval that contains $ \{ 1,2\}$ must also contain 1.5?

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

How do I prove that every open interval that contains $ \{ 1,2\}$ must also contain 1.5?

$| x -x_0| \lt \varepsilon$ if and only if $x$ is in the interval $(x_o -\varepsilon, x_o + \varepsilon)$

We had to prove this statement before so I am wondering if I use that to prove this?

We haven't talked about the radius of a ball or anything like that.  Very basic introduction to nearness in terms of a limit in calculus.

Comment: How do you define interval?

Comment: It follows directly from the definition of open interval. $(a,b) = \{c \in \mathbb{R} : a < c <b\}$ .

Comment: This has nothing to do with openness, any interval containing $a,b$ must also contain $[a,b]$.

Comment: A nitpick: an open interval  can't _contain_ $\{1,2\}$ (although we all know what you mean). An open interval is a set of points in $\mathbb R$, and so is $\{1,2\}$. So you have to say "every open interval that contains $1$ and $2$".

Comment: @TonyK: I do not understand your point. Surely it is correct to write $\{1,2\} \subset (0,3)$ and  $(0,3)\supset \{1,2\}$.  The $\supset$ symbol is often read as  "contains"  and the $\subset$ symbol as "is contained in".

Comment: @MJD: Hmm. I was taught that a set contains its elements (not its subsets). Perhaps fashions have changed.

Comment: I think this difference is generally indicated by using $\subset$ rather than $\in$; for instance $\{1,2\} \in \{\{1,2\},\{1\}\}$, but $\{1,2\}\not\in (0,3)$ (i.e. it wouldn't be correct to say $\{1,2\}$ is "an element of" $(0,3)$. Of course, "contains" could well refer to either symbol, but I think from the context, it means "$\subset$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could use this (though I don't think you necessarily have to, depending on your definitions):

> $| x -x_0| \lt \varepsilon$ if and only if $x$ is in the interval $(x_o -\varepsilon, x_o + \varepsilon)$

Now, suppose $(x_0 - \varepsilon, x_0 + \varepsilon)$ is an interval containing $1$ and $2$. Then $|1 - x_0| < \varepsilon$, and $|2 - x_0| < \varepsilon$. Now we need to show $|1.5 - x_0| < \varepsilon$.

Here's a hint:

$$
|3 - 2x_0| = |2 - x_0 + 1 - x_0| \leq |2 - x_0| + |1 - x_0|
$$

Comment: What definitions would I need to avoid this?

Comment: As @mrka notes, if $(a,b) := \{ c \in \mathbb R : a < c < b\}$, and $(a,b)$ contains $1$ and $2$, then by the definition, $a < 1$, $b > 2$. Since $a < 1 < 1.5 < 2 < b$, $1.5 \in (a,b)$ as well.

Comment: Can I replace $ |2 - x_0| + |1 - x_0|$ with $\varepsilon$ which would then get me to the  inequality I need of  $|1.5 - x_0| < \varepsilon$

Comment: No, but you can replace it by $2\varepsilon$. Note also that $|3 - 2x_0| = 2|1.5 - x_0|$.

Comment: ah that's what I meant!  Thanks!